# how to get the path from image_cropper in flutter?

Tags: laravel, flutter, api, image-cropper

I want to upload the cropped image in the server but I don't know how to get image path from the cropper. how do I get the path from the cropper. below is my code for cropping and for uploading the cropped image.

this is my code for cropping.

```
    `void _cropImage(filePath) async {
CroppedFile? _croppedFile = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
  sourcePath: filePath,
  aspectRatioPresets: [
    CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
    CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
    CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
    CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
    CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
  ],
  uiSettings: [
    AndroidUiSettings(
        toolbarTitle: 'Cropper',
        toolbarColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
        initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
        lockAspectRatio: false),
    IOSUiSettings(
      title: 'Cropper',
    ),
  ],);
//     compressFormat: ImageCompressFormat.jpg);
// cropImagePath.value = croppedFile!.path;
if (_croppedFile != null) {
  setState(() {
    imageFile = _croppedFile.path;
  });
}
```

}

this is my code for uploading

```
    `uploadImage() async {
var request = http.MultipartRequest(
    'POST', Uri.parse('http://hsdgfddf/api/examples/add'));
request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
    'picture', croppedfile!.path));

http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
}
else {
  print(response.reasonPhrase);
}
```

}

Comment: for example, use [fromStream](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartFile/MultipartFile.fromString.html), not `fromPath`

Comment: how? im sorry im new in flutter

Comment: most likely `croppedfile!.path` is wrong, what do you see if you `print` it? is it possible to open a `File` with it? if not, you need a `Stream`

Comment: its showing the image from the app but when I click upload its printing Not Found

Comment: this is not what I asked

Comment: Null check operator used on a null value

Comment: so `croppedfile` is null, you cannot use any properties of it

Comment: so how will I get the image from CroppedFile?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image path when you set it once you received the modified cropped image is received.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how? please tell me?

Comment: @jemzy try this (refer to my second answer)

Answer (score -1):

try this

var request = http.MultipartRequest(
'POST',
Uri.parse("API"),
);

```
Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "multipart/form-data"};

request.files.add(
  http.MultipartFile(
    'pic' //picture_index,
    selectedImage.readAsBytes().asStream(),
    selectedImage.lengthSync(),
    filename: croppedImage.path.split('/').last,
  ),
);

request.headers.addAll(headers);
print("request: " + request.toString());
var res = await request.send();

http.Response response = await http.Response.fromStream(res);
```